# How do I create cinematic (trailer like) shots of my game?

Tags: animation, rendering, camera, movement, unreal-4

---

**Background**

We are in the midst of developing a trailer for our game.

It is a 3rd person adventure platformer. As such, the camera is an over the shoulder position, which is great for gameplay, but not so much for creating cinematic shots of our game.

---

**Problem**

I need to create cinematic shots of my game. This means I need to use separate camera angles to record gameplay.

As far as I am aware, I can only record the active viewport with Unreal, which leaves me stumped as to how I am supposed to play the game and record a moving camera at the same time.

---

**What I have tried**

I have attempted to use the `level sequencer recorder` to track the actors required, then playing the game and recording all my actions into the sequence created. From here, I can use a cinematic camera in a viewport and play the sequencer in the level (whilst recording), or directly rendering out the sequence.

Issue with this: The output of the sequence when rendered out is never the same as what is recorded. This issue seems to vary between machines we do it on. For instance, at my work PC, the sequence that gets played had the player mesh rotated to a completely wrong angle.

A colleague has also tried this same method, but for him some of the animations for the main character simply do not play.

---

**Question**

How do I create cinematic footage of my game akin to my proposal?

Is the level sequencer recorder the correct approach to be taking?

How have you done this in the past for your game etc.?

Answer (score 1):

If you're having issues with the Sequence Recorder, the **Replay System** might be an interesting alternative for you: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Replay/index.html

By combining that with a camera sequence, you should be able to put together a proper gameplay trailer.

If that doesn't work for you, you could also try the new Take Recorder, which seems to be the way to go now (as mentioned in the [Sequence Recorder page](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Sequencer/Workflow/SequenceRecorder/index.html)). Here's a guide: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Sequencer/Workflow/TakeRecorder/UsingTR/index.html

Hopefully it will give you better results.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for the alternatives! I'll be sure to check those out!